# Wifi driver error: Unknown header type 7f

Tags: wifi, drivers, network-interface, realtek

**Wifi connection is not working with Lenovo Thinkpad**. Although ethernet connection is working.
I've already install  `Ubuntu 20.04.1`:

`Linux username-ThinkPad-E490 5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 00:24:02 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

The notebook is `Lenovo Thinkpad E490` (new)

I tried these things:

1. `$ ip address`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback ...
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ...
3: wlp5s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ...
```

2. `$ lspci -kv`

```
05:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
    !!! Unknown header type 7f
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_pci
    Kernel modules: rtwpci
```

3. `$ sudo modprobe 8822be`

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module 8822be not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic
```

4. `$ ls /lib/firmware/rtlwifi | grep rtl8822`

```
rtl8822befw.bin
```

I don't know what is happens. What means **!!! Unknown header type 7f** ?
The driver seems to be installed, although the interface is not up.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem on Lenovo Legion Y530: Ubuntu 18.04 LTE

```
uname -r
5.4.0-42-generic


$ sudo lspci -v

07:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
!!! Unknown header type 7f
Kernel driver in use: r8822be
Kernel modules: rtwpci, r8822be

$ sudo modprobe 8822be

modprobe: FATAL: Module 8822be not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-42- 
generic
```

Comment: Let me know when you figure out what is going on! Thank you Kir